# angular ngFor warning - Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angularjs

need help understanding this error message,
on the UI side everything seems to work ok, so i am not sure why I am seeing this.

```
Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

this is the for loop:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let draft of drafts; let i = index">
        <td  width="1%">                        
         <xerox-checkbox [(ngModel)]="draft.selected" ></xerox-checkbox>
        </td>     
        <td>
   code truncated.
```

and the Error message:

```
DraftsComponent.html:29 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:5642)
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3157)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9246)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DraftsComponent.html:96)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
```

Drafts array of objects:

```
drafts[{"id":"1000019","printerName":"Regin1","printerState":"US","userId":"userId1","userEmail":null,"aaName":"","sale":null},
           {"id":"1000018","printerName":null,"printerState":"US","userId":"userId2","userEmail":null,"aaName":"","sale":null},
           {"id":"1000014","printerName":"my new entry","printerState":"US","userId":"userId4","userEmail":null,"aaName":"","sale":null}]
```

Comment: Can you log `drafts` variable ?

Comment: added to the question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

On your template you use `drafts[_].selected`, but the attribut doesn't exists on the shard log of the variable.

Can you provide more details ? And/Or a https://stackblitz.com/ to play with ?

I've made a working minimal sample :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zzdpk3?file=src/app/app.component.html

PS : what is `adp-checkbox` ? I've found nothing about it on Google.

Comment: Hi , I added selected property it didn't make any difference, ill try to put it on stackblitz.com/